# Microsoft Edge: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd

Tags: xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

Running on Windows 10, Microsoft Edge.  I have an app installed locally on my machine in IIS (10.119.103.10) which is trying to make requests to another machine on the network (10.119.103.2) which is setup to use CORS.

This all works in chrome and internet explorer ... here is a test case

```js
function LOG(message) {
        var el = document.createElement('pre');
        el.textContent = message;
        output.appendChild(el);
}
function xhrtest(url) {
        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        LOG("OPEN " + url);
        XHR.open("GET", url, true);
        XHR.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
                LOG('READY ' + XHR.readyState + ' STATUS ' + XHR.status + ' ' + XHR.statusText + ' TYPE ' + XHR.responseType);
                LOG(XHR.response);
        }
        LOG("SEND");
        XHR.send();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="xhrtest('http://10.119.103.2/~adf/RMC2/trunk/server/?r=get')">XHR TEST</button>
<hr/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

In Microsoft Edge however, I get the following error

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete
>   the operation due to error 00002efd.

The client (XMLHttpRequest) isn't even attempting to connect to the server, it bails immediately.  The test case producing this output:-

```
OPEN http://10.119.103.2/~adf/RMC2/trunk/server/?r=get 
SEND 
READY 4 STATUS 0  TYPE
```

I suspect this is something to do with private networks though really I have no idea, nor any idea how to resolve it.

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd" problem whenever my webpage would try to connect with other web server via ajax. My page was working fine in all other browsers even in IE 11. I resolve it by turning off the smart screen filter in Edge browser. I think smart screen filter blocks ajax communication with websites which it think suspicious or low reputation.[check this link for more info](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/windows-network-security/lesson6/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing something similar .... I have a Windows phone App developed using Cordova and the VS2015 tool set. When I use our company WIFI or Mobile Data connection, the AJAX request works fine. But when using non-company wifi e.g at home then I get error "XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ee2, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ee2" with response "readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error".

Can you try connecting via a 3G/4G connection and see if that works.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I have pinned it down to to use cases:- using the Windows 10 Edge browser on the Laptop the

Comment: Two use cases:- not AJAX related. Browsing  from MSEdge on Laptop, the url succeeds. If I visit the same site using an Edge Browser on UWPhone, the Client hello handshake fails as the server does not respond to the client hello. The strange thing is that problem on the UWP edge browser only occurs when using external (non-company) WIFI, if I connect via 3G/4G or via our company wifi then the  Client hello succeeds. I have captured the client hello in both cases and they are identical. The logs are being analysed by our network server people. Currently awaiting their response.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it turned out that Wifi property `Make this PC discoverable` was turned off. Turning it on fixed the issue.